# SSL certificates present for some clients and missing for others

Tags: ssl-certificate

I just changed the SSL certificates for one particular domain on AppEngine. While I expect that there might be a propagation delay with Google's systems before the new certs (CRT, IA) can take effect, I am not having a problem accessing the website with SSL via a number of browsers on a number of machines, but I -am- consistently getting a verification error from a Python client. I am also consistently getting a "SSL certificates not found" on every online SSL-checker website that I find.

Does anyone have a suggestion why this is happening?

Comment: "getting a verification error from the command-line" - in response to what?

Comment: From a Python client attempting to connect to the URL (HTTPS).

Answer (score 1):

It might indicate that AppEngine is not sending the Intermediate certificate. You can verify this with openssl:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect yourapp.com:443
```

The output will show all certificates in the chain sent by the web server. If it only shows 1, you'll need to re-upload the certificate.

Concatenating the intermediate certificate is pretty easy, just take you favorite text editor, input the certificate at the top and the intermediate at the next line and you'll have a file looking like this:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your SSL certificate: BASE64 encoded stuff) 
-----END CERTIFICATE----- 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- 
(Your Intermediate certificate: more BASE64 encoded stuff) 
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I think there's some wicked caching going on. The Python client is now passing, but I've since, deliberately, removed the certificate and the Python is still working and the digicert website is still passing, but the "openssl s_client" is coming up empty.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there could be a delay of, at most, around an hour with AppEngine. Also, "openssl s_client" works to check the hostname, but make sure to provide the "-servername" parameter.